# How to align text input on Tkinter grid

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm sure it's a quick fix, but I just can't seem to figure out how to align my entry text boxes (in column 4) with the images & buttons in (columns 1-3). Here is my code, and an image of actual verse desired output:

I've tried changing the column and row position of t1 - t3 (CHAPTER NUMBER INPUTS) but they still appear shifted below the other grid "boxes" instead of in the same row.

```
   from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

# pip install pillow
# from pillow import Image, ImageTk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

WD = Tk() # window
FM = Frame(WD) # frame
FM.grid(row=0,column=0)

# LABELS
lblA = Label(FM, text="Image 1", font=("Arial Bold", 20))
lblB = Label(FM, text="Image 2", font=("Arial Bold", 20))
lblC = Label(FM, text="Image 3", font=("Arial Bold", 20))

# LABEL POSITIONS
lblA.grid(row=0, column=1)
lblB.grid(row=1, column=1)
lblC.grid(row=2, column=1)

# CHAPTER NUMBER INPUTS
#ch1 = ""
t1 = Text()
t2 = Text()
t3 = Text()
# t1.config(wrap=WORD)
# t2.config(wrap=WORD)
# t3.config(wrap=WORD)
#ch1_entry = Entry(FM, width=8, textvariable=ch1)
t1.grid(row=0, column=4)#, sticky=(S, W))
t2.grid(row=1, column=4)#, sticky=(S, W))
t3.grid(row=2, column=4)#, sticky=(S, W))

# BUTTONS
btnA1 = Button(FM, text ="Move Up")
btnA2 = Button(FM, text ="Move Down")
btnB1 = Button(FM, text ="Move Up")
btnB2 = Button(FM, text ="Move Down")
btnC1 = Button(FM, text ="Move Up")
btnC2 = Button(FM, text ="Move Down")

# BUTTON POSITIONS
btnA1.grid(row=0,column=2, sticky="n")
btnA2.grid(row=0,column=2, sticky="s")
btnB1.grid(row=1,column=2, sticky="n")
btnB2.grid(row=1,column=2, sticky="s")
btnC1.grid(row=2,column=2, sticky="n")
btnC2.grid(row=2,column=2, sticky="s")

# IMAGES
load1 = Image.open("parrot.jpg")
renderA = ImageTk.PhotoImage(load1)
renderB = ImageTk.PhotoImage(load1)
renderC = ImageTk.PhotoImage(load1)
imgA = Label(FM, image=renderA)
imgB = Label(FM, image=renderB)
imgC = Label(FM, image=renderC)

imgA.image = renderA
imgB.image = renderB
imgC.image = renderC

# IMAGE POSITIONS
imgA.grid(row=0, column=3)
imgB.grid(row=1, column=3)
imgC.grid(row=2, column=3)




#root = Tk()
#app = Window(root)
#root.wm_title("Tkinter window")
#root.geometry("400x120")
WD.mainloop()
```

[image: Actual vs. Desired layout]

Comment: You didn't specify a parent widget for your `Text`s.  They are part of an entirely separate grid than your images and buttons.

Answer (score 0):

The images, buttons, and label are children of `FM` but the text widgets are children of root. If you want the text widgets aligned with everything else then they also need to be children of `FM`

```
t1 = Text(FM)
t2 = Text(FM)
t3 = Text(FM)
```

If you want the image to control the height of a row, you can give the text widget a height of 1 and then use the `sticky` attribute to cause it to expand to fill the height created by the image.

```
t1 = Text(FM, height=1)
t2 = Text(FM, height=1)
t3 = Text(FM, height=1)
...
t1.grid(row=0, column=4, sticky="nsew")
t2.grid(row=1, column=4, sticky="nsew")
t3.grid(row=2, column=4, sticky="nsew")
```